# Android application stops working after launching bufferedRead

Tags: java, android

I have some problems with Android Java programming.

This is my situation:

- I am trying to load text lines from a text file.
- I will make every line as a separate string variable which will be
  saved in an `ArrayList`.
- I have no problems with running the application, but it fails when I
  press the button that will send a variable to method where the
  application will use to make every line as separate questions.
- The whole screen freezes after pressing the button on my phone.

I do not know how to fix this. Furthermore, I could not get errors from the logcat, very weird.

I am newbie in programming but I try my best, so any help is appreciated. Please ask if you did not understand or want more information, peace. I have fixed the solutions I got, but I still have problems with the code, and I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the code:

```
   public void levelOne(View v)throws IOException{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pageBeforeAction.class);
    Button buttond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    createQuestions("hogskoleprovet.txt");
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void levelTwo(View v) throws IOException{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, pageBeforeAction.class);
    Button buttonC = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
    createQuestions("hogskoleprovet.txt");
    startActivity(intent);

}

public void createQuestions(String hogskoleprovet) throws IOException{


    InputStream iS = getResources().getAssets().open(hogskoleprovet);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));

    String question = reader.readLine();
    String answer = reader.readLine();
    String answerOne = reader.readLine();
    String answerTwo = reader.readLine();
    String answerThree = reader.readLine();
    String answerFour = reader.readLine();       

    while(reader != null){
        question = reader.readLine();
        answer = reader.readLine();
        answerOne = reader.readLine();
        answerTwo = reader.readLine();
        answerThree = reader.readLine();
        answerFour = reader.readLine();
        Question q = new Question (question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
        mQuestions.add(q);    break;        }reader.close();    }
```

This is the output of my logcat:

```
 26837-26837/com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet, PID: 26837
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3969)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19422)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964) at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4637)
```

Comment: from your code, After executing `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));` you need to enter the values for question,answer,answerOne ,answerTwo ,answerThree  and answerFour . Are you doing that??

Comment: I think that I am doing that. The values will be determined according to the array. Now I have finally gotten the error from the log cat:

Comment: and what is the error???could you please post the Logcat

Comment: 04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? D/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0x104e80
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device

Comment: Could you please edith the question and post the full Logcat..

Comment: 04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? E/﹕ TIMA: tima-pkm--Unable to start TZ app; errno = 9
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? D/﹕ TAL: TIMA_backend_open--int8_t TIMA_backend_open(void**, appID, uint32_t, uint32_t)
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? D/﹕ TIMA: QCOM_backend_open--int8_t QCOM_backend_open(void**, appID, uint32_t, uint32_t)
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? D/﹕ TIMA: tima-pkm--Attempting to load TZAPPS
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? D/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ QSEECom_get_handle sb_length = 0x104e80
04-18 19:12:22.933  20787-20787/? E/QSEECOMAPI:﹕ Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device

Comment: Delta = 10
04-18 19:12:25.823  20542-20647/? I/System.out﹕ SyncAdapterThread-2 calls detatch()
04-18 19:12:25.843  20542-20647/? E/Gmail﹕ IOException: Unable to resolve host "android.clients.google.com": No address associated with hostname

04-18 19:12:25.893    1004-1004/? D/STATUSBAR-IconMerger﹕ checkOverflow(1120), More:false, Req:false Child:1
04-18 19:12:26.053      788-903/? D/SyncManager﹕ failed sync operation

Comment: 04-18 19:12:26.053     788-1177/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Killing 19872:com.android.defcontainer/u0a4 (adj 15): empty #31
04-18 19:12:26.083    1910-1935/? W/ResourceType﹕ Failure getting entry for 0x7f02091b (t=1 e=2331) in package 0 (error -75)
04-18 19:12:26.163   1245-20833/? I/GCoreUlr﹕ Uploading GCM registration ID for account#-12#
04-18 19:12:26.183   1245-20833/? W/GmsApplication﹕ Using Auth Proxy for data requests.
04-18 19:12:27.733      788-902/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
04-18 19:12:28.353  20747-20747/? I/dumpstate﹕ waiting for zip started

Comment: Please dont post it in comments..instead edit the question and post it there..

Comment: It does not want to work with me when I try to put it as editing. I am sorry

Comment: Still, it does not work. Instead of having an infinite problem in the loop. I have another problem, when I press the button for sending a variable it says something like:

Answer (score 1):

You are getting stuck in an infinite loop, here:

```
while (reader != null)
```

The value of `reader` is never set to null anywhere, so you get stuck in the loop.

Comment: But I have put the reader as not equal as null, why should it be an infinite loop then?